# Publishing ASP.NET Core application to Azure via PowerShell getting 502 (Bad Gateway) In Azure

Tags: powershell, azure, asp.net-core

How can I publish my ASP.NET Core application to Azure?

What I have done so far is created a script that I got from official Azure/Microsoft documents that call on default-publish.ps1 script that Visual Studio also uses. The script looks as follows:

```
param($websiteName, $packOutput)

$website = Get-AzureWebsite -Name $websiteName

# get the scm url to use with MSDeploy.  By default this will be the second in the array
$msdeployurl = $website.EnabledHostNames[1]


$publishProperties = @{'WebPublishMethod'='MSDeploy';
                        'MSDeployServiceUrl'=$msdeployurl;
                        'DeployIisAppPath'=$website.Name;
                        'Username'=$website.PublishingUsername;
                        'Password'=$website.PublishingPassword}


$publishScript = "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\Publish\Scripts\default-publish.ps1"


. $publishScript -publishProperties $publishProperties  -packOutput $packOutput
```

Now this script calls upon the default-publish.ps1 script, given you provide the Azure website name and the dotnet publish artifact. I have updated my default-publish.ps1 script to exactly what is currently in the [repo](https://github.com/aspnet/vsweb-publish/tree/master/samples).

The issue is that when I publish to Azure a 502 Bad Gateway error is returned. Even with a project created using the new tooling update, I cannot seem to publish it to Azure correctly.

Comment: Bad gateway most likely means that your application was not started at all. How do you publish your application before deploying it to Azure? How does your web.config look like after you published your application? I think what happens is that your web.config has just placeholder values. Out of the box the application is setup to run publish-iis tool after publishing the application to fix up your config. I think either this step is not happening or - if you moved from RC1 to RC2 - web.config is not in the right location since it should be now in the approot and not wwwroot.

Comment: We have a script on CI that runs dotnet restore, dotnet build and a dotnet publish into a location, and then we use the vs publish script as found on the repo mentioned in the post to do the actual azure deployment. This project was always RC2 from the beginning webconfig is verbatim the default one you get when you start a new RC2 project via the new VS tooling update. web.config is in the approot right alongside startup.cs and program.cs.

Comment: I wrote a post about running ASP.NET Core apps with IIS which contains entire section on troubleshooting 502.3 Bad Gatway: https://blog.3d-logic.com/2016/06/08/running-asp-net-core-applications-with-iis-and-antares/. You may find it helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a web.config? Is it included in your project.json like this:

```
"publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "web.config"
    ]
  }
```

Your web.config will look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" 
           resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" 
                stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout"  
                forwardWindowsAuthToken="false"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

*Note:* The environment variables LAUNCHER_PATH and LAUNCHER_ARGS may be the source of your issue. You are attempting to launch the publishing scripts that visual studio runs, it is possible that visual studio sets the values in the environment before running the scripts.

To get an RC2 site up and running on an Azure VM, I had to change that line to look like this:

```
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments="./YourAppEntryPoint.dll" 
            stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" 
            forwardWindowsAuthToken="false"/>
```

Try setting your web.config with the explicit values. If your deploy works, then you know it's the missing ENVVARS that are messing it up.

Comment: publish-iis tool should be [wired as a postpublish script](https://github.com/aspnet/cli-samples/blob/master/HelloMvc/project.json#L35-L37) and it would fix the config for you accordingly.

Comment: Only if you are using visual studio.

Comment: No, you can set it up yourself. publish-iis is not a VS tool is a general tool.